# How to insert google maps(and set user location, just like Uber) in Ionic 1?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, plugins

I am currently new with Ionic Framework also the Angular.
Right now, i am making a project using Ionic 1, and got asked to display the map and set user location using Google Maps (just like Uber does).
I already installed the cordova plugin, now i have to insert it to my ionic project, what should i do first?

[The HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRINo.png)

[The Plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flJTi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [this tutorial](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/10/implement-google-maps-using-ionicframework/) made by Nic Raboy. He explains how to implement the map using ionic v1, but always the best documentation is for google map api itself. Since some of the functionalities may have been changed.

Comment: I'm kind of new with ionic and plugin :s. By the way, how do you use plugin in ionic?

Comment: It depends on plugin, you probably can use npm or bower or cordova cli to install the plugin.
For example for google map plugin you can use 
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git
cordova cli, but for better understanding, read repository of plugin.